# How to make Coinbase API return wallet balance in local currency instead of wallet currency

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, coinbase-api

I'm working on an Alexa skill (in python) that uses Oauth2 authentication and will tell me the total value of my Coinbase portfolio. I can get the balances of all the wallets in the account but the values returned are in the crypto amount in the wallet.  Is there a request format that can be made to get the wallet value converted to the local currency listed in the user profile of the Coinbase account?

For instance the reqeust in python:

url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts?access_token={}".format(account_linking_token)
acct_data = requests.get(url).json()

returns the data for all the account wallets and the Bitcoin amount data looks like this:
'balance': {'amount': '0.05240601',
'currency': 'BTC'},

Is there an option to add to the request call to have the amount returned in 'USD' or whatever the local currency is in the Coinbase profile?

Thanks.

Note: I have tried incorporating the coinbase python module into the Alexa skill but I could not get it work so after days of trying with it I just used the direct request.

Comment: why do you not just use conversion factors?

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I ended up doing.   I was just wondering if there was a way to request the balance in the local currency and have the api convert it before it sends it.  I'm just a beginner and I guess I'll do the conversion if there's no other way.

Comment: conversion is the easiest way since it sounds like they dont do it on their end, I mean its technically the same thing it would just be them doing it on their end instead of you doing it.